# Show that $\operatorname{dim}V=|W|$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $K$ be a field, let $W$ be a set and let $V$ be the vector space of all functions from $W$ to $K$. Show that if $W$ is finite then $\operatorname{dim}V=|W|$.

I would assume that I need to somehow show that $W$ is a basis for $V$ and the result will follow. I'm not sure how to do that or if this is even the right way to go about it though.

Comment: The set $W$ is not itself a basis for $V$, but for each $w\in W$ you can define $f_w\in V$ by $f(w)=1$ and $f(w')=0$ whenever $w'\neq w$.  Then $\{f_w:w\in W\}$ is a basis for $V$.

Comment: Let's call $w_1\dots w_n$ the elements of $W$. A function $f:W\to\mathbb{K}$ is then specified by it's value on $w_i$. Consider the set of functions $f_i:W\to\mathbb{K}$ so that $f_i(w_j)$ is $1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise. Is this a base? Why? Why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $W=\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$ and define the functions
$$
g_i\colon W\to K \quad(i=1,2,\dots,n)
$$
by
$$
g_i(a_j)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $i=j$} \\[4px]
0 & \text{if $i\ne j$}
\end{cases}
$$
Now prove that $\{g_1,g_2,\dots,g_n\}$ is a basis for the space of functions $W\to K$.

Hint: if $f\colon W\to K$ is a function and $f(a_i)=\beta_i\in K$, then 
$$
f=\beta_1g_1+\dots+\beta_ng_n
$$

---

A bit of “philosophy". If we have a function $f\colon W\to K$, we can define $f_i$ as the function that takes the value $f(a_i)$ at $a_i$ and zero elsewhere. Then, by definition of sum of functions,
$$
f=f_1+f_2+\dots+f_n\tag{1}
$$
because at $a_i$ we have
$$
f_1(a_i)+\dots+f_i(a_i)+\dots+f_n(a_i)=f_i(a_i)=f(a_i)
$$
so the right-hand side coincides with the left-hand side in $(1)$.

Now, if $f(a_i)=f_i(a_i)=\beta_i\in K$, we clearly have
$$
f_i(a_i)=\beta_i g_i
$$
and we get the statement above.

Now prove the set $\{g_1,\dots,g_n\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: Could you explain why you knew to define $f_i$ in that way? And could you expand on your hint please?

Comment: @user374859 I expanded my answer, but now you should try and work out the details.